# How to keep page anchor even if page refreshed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to retain the navigation anchor on a link even if someone refreshes the page.
This is my code

```
<nav class='navbar'>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" class="current" id='navshow1'>home</a> </li>
  <li><a href="#whatis" class="current" id='navshow2'>what is this site</a></li>
  <li><a href="#test" class="current" id='navshow3'>test</a> </li>
</nav>
```

```
  $('li').click(function(){
   $('li').removeClass("active");
       $(this).addClass("active");
  });
```

jsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/p650f8or/

So if someone clicks "whatis", the URL in the address bar becomes
mywebsite.com/page#whatis

How do I retain this if someone refreshes the page?

Comment: you would need to use locastorage or cookie or backend to manage state

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest answer for that would be:

```js
// this will extract #whatis if you are on eg. https://mywebsite.com/page#whatis.
const { hash } = window.location;

// or if your prefer the older way
var hash = window.location.hash;
```

To get that value initially, you can attach a onload kinda method and set the active list element depending on the hrefs of the containing anchors, but that depends on what you wanna do.
Hope that helped.